# Unable to get wireless in a HP G7000 laptop

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Trying to get wireless in an old HP G7000 laptop to no avail. Already installed firmware-b43-installer but still nothing.

This is the wifi card:

```
~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 02)
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

And output of what is now:

```
~$ grep 'blacklist b43' /etc/modprobe.d/*
~$

~$ lsmod | egrep 'wl|b43|ssb'
b43 398950 0
bcma 46583 1 b43
mac80211 580709 1 b43
cfg80211 433826 2 b43,mac80211
ssb_hcd 12757 0
ssb 55983 2 b43,ssb_hcd

~$ sudo modprobe -rf b43
~$

~$ sudo modprobe -v b43
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.0-13-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.0-13-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko

~$ dmesg | grep b43
[ 29.253267] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 13)
[ 29.285790] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 4, Type 2 (G), Revision 9
[ 29.285806] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2050, Revision 2, Version 0
[ 29.296837] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode13.fw failed with error -2
[ 29.296872] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode13.fw failed with error -2
[ 29.296930] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode13.fw failed with error -2
[ 29.296949] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode13.fw failed with error -2
[ 29.296954] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode13.fw" not found
[ 29.296959] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode13.fw" not found
[ 29.296963] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[ 1297.396699] b43-wlan ERROR: Dual-core devices are not supported
[ 1297.396716] b43: probe of ssb0:0 failed with error -524
[ 1932.298691] b43-wlan ERROR: Dual-core devices are not supported
[ 1932.298706] b43: probe of ssb0:0 failed with error -524
[ 1969.802083] b43-wlan ERROR: Dual-core devices are not supported
[ 1969.802099] b43: probe of ssb0:0 failed with error -524
[ 4211.112275] b43-wlan ERROR: Dual-core devices are not supported
[ 4211.112291] b43: probe of ssb0:0 failed with error -524
[ 8316.908456] b43-wlan ERROR: Dual-core devices are not supported
[ 8316.908472] b43: probe of ssb0:0 failed with error -524

~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

~$ /etc/init.d/networking restart
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.75" (uid=999 pid=7583 comm="stop networking ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.76" (uid=999 pid=7577 comm="start networking ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:8d:b3:bf  
          inet addr:10.40.111.20  Bcast:10.40.111.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:38ff:fe8d:b3bf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:74536 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:4 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:91438000 (91.4 MB)  TX bytes:6053996 (6.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:509283 (509.2 KB)  TX bytes:509283 (509.2 KB)

~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall firmware-b43-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,126 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 160409 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-b43-installer_1%3a019-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-b43-installer (1:019-1) over (1:019-1) ...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (1:019-1) ...
No chroot environment found. Starting normal installation
--2015-02-12 15:13:04--  http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
Resolving www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)... 173.254.28.119
Connecting to www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)|173.254.28.119|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13514651 (13M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2’

broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2                100%[================================================================================================>]  12.89M   136KB/s   in 5m 25s s

2015-02-12 15:18:40 (40.7 KB/s) - ‘broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2’ saved [13514651/13514651]

Deleting old extracted firmware...
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_ap.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_sta.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/README
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wlconfig_lx_shared
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl.mk
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl_default
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl_hnd
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wlconfig_nomimo
This file is recognised as:
  filename   :  wl_apsta.o
  version    :  666.2
  MD5        :  e1b05e268bcdbfef3560c28fc161f30e
Extracting b43/lp0initvals14.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals17.fw
Extracting b43/ucode17_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_lp.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1initvals27.fw
Extracting b43/lp2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn3bsinitvals21.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_sslpn.fw
  ucode time:     01:15:07
Extracting b43/ucode25_lcn.fw
Extracting b43/ucode21_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals14.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode20_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/lp1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/lp2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/n2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn4bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_sslpn_nobt.fw
  ucode date:     2011-02-23
Extracting b43/n1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/n1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode22_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/ht0initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ucode33_lcn40.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/lcn400bsinitvals33.fw
Extracting b43/ucode14.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/lp1bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/n16initvals30.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/lcn400initvals33.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/n18initvals32.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals11.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0absinitvals11.fw
Extracting b43/ucode21_sslpn_nobt.fw
  ucode time:     01:15:07
Extracting b43/ucode26_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/n2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn3initvals21.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn4initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/pcm5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode22_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode9.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/lp1initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1bsinitvals27.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode32_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/n18bsinitvals32.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode24_lcn.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals17.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals15.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode20_sslpn_nobt.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/lp1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode5.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/ucode19_sslpn_nobt.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode11.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ht0initvals29.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode29_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode19_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/ucode30_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/n16bsinitvals30.fw
Extracting b43/ucode25_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode24_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode27_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ht0bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ucode13.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/ucode15.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals15.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals11.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/ht0bsinitvals29.fw

~$ sudo ls /lib/firmware/b43
a0g0bsinitvals5.fw   b0g0initvals9.fw     lcn1initvals25.fw  lp0initvals14.fw    n0bsinitvals25.fw   pcm5.fw        ucode14.fw         ucode24_lcn.fw
a0g0bsinitvals9.fw   ht0bsinitvals26.fw   lcn1initvals26.fw  lp0initvals15.fw    n0initvals11.fw     sslpn0bsinitvals16.fw  ucode15.fw         ucode24_mimo.fw
a0g0initvals5.fw     ht0bsinitvals29.fw   lcn2bsinitvals24.fw    lp0initvals16.fw    n0initvals16.fw     sslpn0initvals16.fw    ucode16_lp.fw          ucode25_lcn.fw
a0g0initvals9.fw     ht0initvals26.fw     lcn2bsinitvals25.fw    lp1bsinitvals20.fw  n0initvals17.fw     sslpn1bsinitvals20.fw  ucode16_mimo.fw        ucode25_mimo.fw
a0g1bsinitvals13.fw  ht0initvals29.fw     lcn2bsinitvals26.fw    lp1bsinitvals22.fw  n0initvals22.fw     sslpn1bsinitvals27.fw  ucode16_sslpn.fw       ucode26_mimo.fw
a0g1bsinitvals5.fw   lcn0bsinitvals24.fw  lcn2initvals24.fw  lp1initvals20.fw    n0initvals24.fw     sslpn1initvals20.fw    ucode16_sslpn_nobt.fw  ucode27_sslpn.fw
a0g1bsinitvals9.fw   lcn0bsinitvals25.fw  lcn2initvals25.fw  lp1initvals22.fw    n0initvals25.fw     sslpn1initvals27.fw    ucode17_mimo.fw        ucode29_mimo.fw
a0g1initvals13.fw    lcn0bsinitvals26.fw  lcn2initvals26.fw  lp2bsinitvals19.fw  n16bsinitvals30.fw  sslpn2bsinitvals19.fw  ucode19_sslpn.fw       ucode30_mimo.fw
a0g1initvals5.fw     lcn0initvals24.fw    lcn400bsinitvals33.fw  lp2initvals19.fw    n16initvals30.fw    sslpn2initvals19.fw    ucode19_sslpn_nobt.fw  ucode32_mimo.fw
a0g1initvals9.fw     lcn0initvals25.fw    lcn400initvals33.fw    n0absinitvals11.fw  n18bsinitvals32.fw  sslpn3bsinitvals21.fw  ucode20_sslpn.fw       ucode33_lcn40.fw
b0g0bsinitvals13.fw  lcn0initvals26.fw    lp0bsinitvals13.fw     n0bsinitvals11.fw   n18initvals32.fw    sslpn3initvals21.fw    ucode20_sslpn_nobt.fw  ucode5.fw
b0g0bsinitvals5.fw   lcn1bsinitvals24.fw  lp0bsinitvals14.fw     n0bsinitvals16.fw   n1bsinitvals20.fw   sslpn4bsinitvals22.fw  ucode21_sslpn.fw       ucode9.fw
b0g0bsinitvals9.fw   lcn1bsinitvals25.fw  lp0bsinitvals15.fw     n0bsinitvals17.fw   n1initvals20.fw     sslpn4initvals22.fw    ucode21_sslpn_nobt.fw
b0g0initvals13.fw    lcn1bsinitvals26.fw  lp0bsinitvals16.fw     n0bsinitvals22.fw   n2bsinitvals19.fw   ucode11.fw     ucode22_mimo.fw
b0g0initvals5.fw     lcn1initvals24.fw    lp0initvals13.fw   n0bsinitvals24.fw   n2initvals19.fw     ucode13.fw     ucode22_sslpn.fw
```

Comment: @AntoineOrsoni> ~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: ~$/etc/init.d/networking restart
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.75" (uid=999 pid=7583 comm="stop networking ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.76" (uid=999 pid=7577 comm="start networking ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: @AntoineOrsoni I don't know how to add code tags in the comments. That was the output I got from /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: @AntoineOrsoni Done. Added to the bottom of the question body

Comment: @AntoineOrsoni Added also the output of ifconfig -a to at the bottom of the question body

Comment: Have you tried to install this driver `http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php` ?

Comment: Any result from `sudo ls /lib/firmware/b43 | grep ucode13.fw`

Comment: @AntoineOrsoni No, the only one I installed was firmware-b43-installer

Comment: @Jeremy31 `~$ sudo ls /lib/firmware/b43 | grep ucode13.fw` and the outoup is `ucode13.fw`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something has gone amiss in your installation of the required firmware. Please make sure you are connected to the internet by ethernet or any other means. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firmware-b43-installer
```

It takes a few moments, so please be patient. When it finishes, check:

```
ls /lib/firmware/b43
```

You should see dozens of firmware files. If so, you should be set. Reboot and tell us the result.

If reboot is not feasible, then:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43  <---if it says it's not loaded, that's fine, just continue
sudo modprobe -r ssb_hcd
sudo modprobe -r ssb  <---if it says in use, see lsmod for users
sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should be working.

This device works quite well in Ubuntu once the proprietary firmware is installed.

Comment: I added the output of the code you provided me at the bottom of the question body. I didn't rebooted, this is a LiveISO environment because I'm trying to figure if the wireless will work before installing it into the all drive. Is the reboot real the only way to check for sure if the wireless will work?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: `~$ sudo modprobe -r ssb
modprobe: FATAL: Module ssb is in use.` and `~$ sudo modprobe -r b43
~$ sudo modprobe b43` but still nothing.

Comment: ssb may also be driving your ethernet. Try: sudo ifconfig eth0 down; sudo modprobe -r ssb; sudo modprobe -r b43; sudo modprobe b43; sudo modprobe ssb.

Comment: `~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down`
`~$ sudo modprobe -r ssb
modprobe: FATAL: Module ssb is in use.`
`~$ sudo modprobe -r b43`
`~$ sudo modprobe b43`
`~$ sudo modprobe ssb`
I then run `~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up` but still no wireless. And thanks kindly for helping me with this issue chili555

Comment: Try: sudo ifconfig eth0 down; sudo modprobe -r b44; sudo modprobe -r ssb; sudo modprobe -r b43; sudo modprobe b43; sudo modprobe ssb.

Comment: `~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down`
`~$ sudo modprobe -r b44`
`~$ sudo modprobe -r ssb
modprobe: FATAL: Module ssb is in use.`
`~$ sudo modprobe -r b43`
`~$ sudo modprobe b43`
`~$ sudo modprobe ssb`. Still nothing. I'm hopping you haven't run out of options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21073/discussion-between-chili555-and-korrigan-nagirrok).

Comment: sorry chili55 the chat room isn't loading. Let me try from another computer

Comment: from the commands you left in the chat room: `~$ sudo modprobe -r bcma
modprobe: FATAL: Module bcma is in use.`
`~$ sudo modprobe -r b43`
`~$ sudo modprobe b43` Still nothing. I'll wait for your return and feedback

Comment: Like you said it worked and I'm now on wireless. Thanks to all that helped me.

Comment: To address `modprobe: FATAL: Module ssb is in use.`, I had to use `sudo modprobe -r ssb_hcd` first. See this in your output from `lsmod | egrep 'wl|b43|ssb'`.

Comment: TLDR: I've encountered this too. The `ssb` module didn't exist in ancient kernels. Basically, if the `b43` can't load its firmwares (some distros don't provide these alas), the `ssb` gets into a confused state and thereafter the `b43` can't load shit, even if it's the only device on the backplane, as it was in my case. One has to `modprobe -r` the `ssb` for `b43` to be able to do anything, even if you put the firmwares in the right place (and `modprobe -r` the b43). And the "dual core" complaint printed by the b43 is extremely unhelpful.